# Looking for failed test runs with a solved defects, to do a retest

Tags: quality-center, hp-quality-center

I am looking for all test cases in the TestLab which have solved defects and don't have the run status 'passed'. To do this, I used the dashboard and build the following report:

```
SELECT BG_BUG_ID,
BG_STATUS,
BG_PRIORITY,
BG_RESPONSIBLE,
LINK.LN_LINK_ID,
LINK.LN_BUG_ID,
LINK.LN_ENTITY_TYPE,
LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID,
LN_TESTCYCL_ID,
TC_CYCLE_ID,
TC_TEST_ORDER,
TC_STATUS,
TS_NAME,
TS_STATUS,
TS_EXEC_STATUS
from (BUG LEFT JOIN LINK ON BG_BUG_ID = LN_BUG_ID )
LEFT JOIN V_LINK_TESTCYCL on LINK.LN_BUG_ID = V_LINK_TESTCYCL.LN_BUG_ID
LEFT JOIN CYCLE ON LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID = CY_CYCLE_ID
LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL on V_LINK_TESTCYCL.LN_TESTCYCL_ID = TC_TESTCYCL_ID
left join test on tc_test_id = ts_test_id

Where

BG_STATUS IN ('100 - closed')
and  BUG.BG_RESPONSIBLE = 'myName' /*Defect.Assigned  to*/
and  TS_EXEC_STATUS IN ('Passed', 'No Run')
ORDER BY BG_BUG_ID
```

But it does not work. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work" ? Do you get an error message, or the outcome does not contain waht you expect ?

Comment: I get test cases who don't have solved bugs.

Comment: @Oliver.  You can link a BUG at many different levels in QC.  That is you can link it to a Test Set, Test Instance, Run, or Step.  Does you organization link consistently at a particular level or could the link be anywhere?  This will dramatically affect the complexity of the query.  Were you aware that QC has an ability to notify a tester when a bug associated to a test goes into a particular state as in Closed, etc.  You may not need this query at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but is the difference here that the requirement is **not passed**:

```
...don't have the run status 'passed'
```

and the query looks for **is passed**

```
TS_EXEC_STATUS IN ('Passed', 'No Run')
```

If you change that line to omit the 'Passed' string, do you get the desired results?

eg

```
TS_EXEC_STATUS IN ('No Run')
```